# C# Refer to a Specific Item in a List<Custom Class>

Tags: c#, list, properties

I created a class of collectables. The class contains a string Name, int Points and int Damage. I created a Collectable instance called "lifeforce" "Life Force" is the Name and Points is set with a value of 1000. When a separate class of immortals is instantiated I add a Collectable instance to a List to the immortal. If I want to see how many points the immortal instance has for his/her Life Force, how do I refer to the lifeforce Points to get the value? Code below.

```
      public class Collectable
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Points { get; set; }
            public int Damage { get; set; }

            public Collectable(string name, int points, int damage)
            {
                Name = name;
                Points = points;
                Damage = damage;

            }
        }

 public class Immortal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Superpower { get; set; }
        public List<Collectable> Carrying { get; set; }
        public string Saying { get; set; }
        public string Bent { get; set; }


        public Immortal(string name, string origin, string superpower, string saying, string bent, Collectable item)
        {
            Name = name;
            Origin = origin;
            Superpower = superpower;
            Saying = saying;
            Bent = bent;
            this.Carrying = new List<Collectable>();
            this.Carrying.Add(item);
        }

        public void Pickup(Collectable item)
        {
            this.Carrying.Add(item);
        }


    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Collectable lifeforce = new Collectable("Life Force", 1000, 0);
                Collectable rubystone = new Collectable("Ruby Stone", 200, 0);
                Collectable bagofdiamonds = new Collectable("Diamond Bag", 500, 0);
                Immortal mighty = new Immortal("Mighty Man", "Mightopolis", "Might", "I am a mighty man!", "good",lifeforce);
    

                foreach (var collecteditem in mighty.Carrying)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Items in bag - " + collecteditem.Name);
    
                }


    
                var lifeforceIndx = 0;
                lifeforceIndx =  mighty.Carrying[0].Points
                Console.WriteLine("Your Life Force is at " + mighty.Carrying[0].Points.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
    
    
            }
```

Comment: fyi -- The `set` for the `Carrying` property should be `private`.

Comment: `var lifeforce = mighty.Carrying.Find(x => x.Name == "Life Force");` <-- Is that what you're trying to do? That's, of course, assuming that you don't have a reference to the original `lifeforce` at that point. Otherwise, you could just use it directly.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: try to keep a semantics coherence between the methods name and what it does:  ***public void Pickup(...***

Comment: I'd make a custom collection class for this and have a method to make it easier to implement and allow indexing by name if that's a common thing to do. Save the linq lookups and have a hash or something. Deal with multiples of the same name. Whatever the requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
Console.WriteLine("Your Life Force is at " + mighty.Carrying.Where(x=>x.Name == "Life Force").Sum(x=>x.Points).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all Collectables named "Life Force" just use

```
Carrying.Where(collectable => string.Equals(collectable.Name, "Life Force", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Ignore case is necessary for cases when Name property has different spelling.

But I recommend to create Enum with collectable types and use this Enum in Collectable class.

For example

```
public class Collectable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public CollectableType Type { get; }

    public Collectable(string name, int points, 
                       int damage, CollectableType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = points;
        Damage = damage;
        Type = type;
     }
}
```

And find all Life Force collectables like shown in code below

```
Collectables.Where(collectable => collectable.Type == CollectableType.LifeForce);
```

If you need sum of points than just add `.Sum(collectable => collectable.Points)` to get

```
Collectables.Where(collectable => collectable.Type == CollectableType.LifeForce)
            .Sum(collectable => collectable.Points);
```

If I get it right then this is the solution.